# Is there an easy way to parse a structured text file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, parsing

I'm trying to parse a text file, but I feel like there must be a better way to do it.

The text file is made up of items, which can contain both key value pairs as well as other items.  I believe the file will only ever go as deep as a grandchild item (e.g. an item within an item, within an item).

Currently I'm iterating through the file line by line, and keeping track of the depth at which I am.  Then once I reach a termination character ('}') and I'm at level 0, I know I've captured a whole parent item.

Since I don't think I've explained it well, my file structure will look similar to this.

```
parent_item {
key: value
key: value
child_item {
    key: value
    key: value
}
child_item {
    key: value
    key: value
    key: value
    grandchild_item {
        key: value
        key: value
    }
}
key: value
key: value
}
parent_item {
    key: value
    key: value
    child_item {
        key: value
        key: value
    }
}
```

Each item can have 0 to many child items, though I don't think it will ever go deeper than 3 levels (parent -> child -> grandchild).

Is there an easier way to parse this, or am I working in the right direction?

Comment: "I'm trying to parse a text file, but I feel like there must be a better way to do it."  -- yes, and plenty of people have already done it.  Don't re-invent the wheel, look for an existing parser out there and use it in your project.

Comment: @rory.ap Maybe I'm searching with the wrong terms, but I'm having trouble finding existing parsers that match my needs.  Any suggestions? Or suggestions for search terms?

Comment: looks like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: @MongZhu It's not JSON, though it is quite similar.

Comment: is it a home made format?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes. Though I don't have control over the format, so I can't change it or use anything different.

Comment: do you have access to the code that creates this format? May be there is the key of how to easily parse it?

Comment: @MongZhu No. I do not.

Comment: care to share your parser here? or is it too much code to post?

Comment: @MongZhu It's kind of a mess right now, as I'm just starting on it.  I'm just trying to get an idea if I'm heading the right way, before I go down this road too far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136885/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-tester101).

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at [Balancing group definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) and may be consider using RegEx to the content between the parentheses. Good luck

Comment: What about using Antlr to generate a C# parser for that language? I know the purpose of tools like Antlr is much bigger than that but using it would reduce the amount of time spended in creating you own parser, which is also prone to errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your file looks almost like JSON, except there are no colons between property names of a complex nested object.  However, it is different enough that you won't be able to use a JSON parser like JSON.NET.

I recommend parsing it manually like you are doing-- but use a stack and state machine.  Your state machine should push to the stack every time you encounter the open curly `{` and pop from the stack when you get the close curly `}`.

Answer (score 1):

Being so similar to JSON, if the formatting is constant (open curly ´{´ and end curly `}` as the last character in the line) you could translate that text into JSON with minor changes. **Warning, not tested, something like** this:

```
StringBuilder jsonEncoded = new StringBuilder();
string[] lines = content.Split("\n");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    if(line.EndsWith("{") || line.EndsWith("}")
        jsonEncoded.AppendLine(line);
    else
        jsonEncoded.AppendLine(line + ",");
}
```

After that, a regular JSON Deseralization would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can trust your source for not messing with this schema you can write a workaround. I have some ideas for you:

## JSON

It looks like json. Maybe you can normalize it, then parse it with JSON.NET.

I just write a ugly but working solution. Try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5YK5dK):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static string Quoterize(string s)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(s, @"\w+", match => "\"" + match + "\"");
    }

    public static string RewriteThisPlease(string s)
    {
        return s
            .Replace("\n", "," + Environment.NewLine)
            .Replace(" ", "")
            .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
            .Replace("{,", "{")
            .Replace(",}", "}");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var k = @""; // your file goes here
        Console.WriteLine("{"+MoveToRegexPlease(Quoterize((k).Replace("{", ": {")))+"}");
    }
}
```

## YAML

It looks like json. It looks even more like yaml. A yaml validator will accept your file after two simples replace:

```
// where k is your file as string
Console.WriteLine(k.Replace("{\n", ":\n").Replace("}",""));
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K9i1nT)

## Homemade

It looks like json. You will find a lot of JSON parser out there, maybe you can fork one and adapt it to works with your case.

## Homework

It looks like json. You will find a lot of JSON parser tutorial out there. Writing a small parser is always a good exercise.

Good luck !

Comment: pretty nice, but in the YAML case I would suggest being a bit more restrict with the replacements. `.Replace("{\n", ":\n")` to avoid messing with string properties/values.

Comment: @bradbury9 nice idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief example (though not carefully tested yet) of using RegEx with [Balancing Group Definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

This example uses the code from the link. I just replaces the parentheses to not change the code and use it as it is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // here I read your posted file
    string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

    input = input.Replace('{', '<');
    input = input.Replace('}', '>');

    string pattern = "^[^<>]*" +
              "(" +
              "((?'Open'<)[^<>]*)+" +
              "((?'Close-Open'>)[^<>]*)+" +
              ")*" +
              "(?(Open)(?!))$";

    //string input = "<abc><mno<xyz>>";

    Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (m.Success == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input: \"{0}\" \nMatch: \"{1}\"", input, m);
        int grpCtr = 0;
        foreach (Group grp in m.Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}: {1}", grpCtr, grp.Value);
            grpCtr++;
            int capCtr = 0;
            foreach (Capture cap in grp.Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}", capCtr, cap.Value);
                capCtr++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match failed.");
    }   

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Copy paste this into a new console project, let it run and take a look at the output. It is confusing in the beginning, but it might give you a starter to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: You shouldnt use abbreviation to name your variables.

Comment: @aloisdg you are entirely right. As you can read in my post this code is from the msdn site. I did not change it on purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Use Serialisation.

In C# you can easily use JSON or XML serialisation.

JSON:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx

A better way would be XML because it is more flexible and has a better support in C#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How does this answer the question? He's asked for an existing tool to read a very specific format.

Comment: That is not JSON, so the JSON Serialization would not work

Comment: Ok, it is not JSON but it is similar! If you write 2 lines of codes to convert it to JSON (replace : with " : " and \n with ",) you have a JSON formatted string.